# Python - empty argument in function

Tags: python

I have a function in my script that takes two arguments and save result to file:

```
def listing(val, ftype):

    with open(sys.argv[3], "a+") as myfile:
        myfile.write(val + ftype + '\n')
    return
```

but I want to use it when only one argument is provided. I can define argument as empty string `''` like that:

```
listing('', '\n[*]Document files found:\n')
```

Is it the only way to deal with empty arguments?

Comment: If the argument is optional, the function declaration should say so: `def listing(ftype, val=None)`. How the function then deals with the value internally is up to you.

Comment: using `sys.argv[3]` in your function sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use default arguments for this purpose

**Using Default Arguments**

```
def listing(val, ftype=''):

    with open(sys.argv[3], "a+") as myfile:
       myfile.write(val + ftype + '\n')
    return
```

Calling :  `listing('\n[*]Document files found:\n')  # need not give second argument`

You could also make this a more generic function **by taking variable number of arguments**

```
def listing(*args):
     with open(sys.argv[3], "a+") as myfile:
          myfile.write("".join(args) + '\n')
     return
```

Calling:  `listing('String1','String2','String3')`

Comment: then `myfile.write("".join(args) + '\n')` will be better than the horrible loop

Comment: Thanks, generic vesion is the best for my needs, as I realized that I'm going to reuse this function even with more than 2 arguments, again thanks a lot!